# How do I delete the last char in the first three line in vim

Tags: vim, editor

I have a file

```
aaaaa0
bbbbb1
ccccc2
ddddd3
eeeee4
fffff5
ggggg6
```

How do I delete the last char in the first three line?
And the file will be

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd3
eeeee4
fffff5
ggggg6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a substitution:

```
:1,3s/.$
```

With a macro:

```
:1,3norm $x
```

See `:help range`, `:help :s`, `:help :norm`, `:help $`, `:help x`.